# Is "My concern is ..." equivalent to "I think ..."?

Tags: phrase-request

I heard from broadcast that some native English speakers introduced their ideas by "My concern is...". I am wondering is this introduction equivalent to "I think..."?

Also, apart from these two ways of beginning a conversation I would like to know the alternative choices.

Comment: alternatives: *"I predict"* (when making a forecast about the future), *"I guess"* (when suggesting that you're not entirely confident about what you are saying...or want to sound resigned to something you cannot control), *"I believe"* (may indicate that you have high confidence in what you're saying, although it can carry the same tone as "I guess"), *"I know"* (when you are certain), *"I ascertain"* (when you want to [annoy dock workers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrJYpActs7g)) :-)

Comment: @HostileFork: Ha Ha Ha :) Thank you so much! They are extremely helpful, especially how to annoy dock workers (I am joking). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking the dictionary definition of [concern](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/concern) in Collins, relevant senses are:

> *noun*
>   4) a matter of interest or importance to one that which relates to or affects one; affair; matter; business
>   5) interest in or regard for a person or thing
>   7) worry; anxiety   ⇒ "to feel concern over one's health"

As you can see, *concern* has more to with interest, importance or worry than using *think*.

> I **think** that food prices will go up.

is saying your thoughts/opinion on the matter.

> My **concern** is that food prices will go up.

is saying the direction or impact of food prices is of interest and/or worry to the speaker.

Answer (score 10):

They are not equivalent.
Use "*my concern is*" when expressing a concern you have.
Use "*I think*" when expressing what you think.

Obviously if you have a concern, you also have a thought about it but they are not always interchangeable.

> My concern is that we might run out of gas

works with either (although using *my concern* is implies that you think running out of gas is a bad thing to have happen, while *I think* just expresses your belief about the outcome in a  neutral manner.)

But

> *My concern is that she looks nice in that dress*

and

> *I think she looks nice in that dress*

imply two very different things.  The first states that you think something bad might happen because she looks nice in her dress, while the second is simply a compliment.

Comment: You should give a better example. The dress example skates far too close to the idea that a woman in nice clothes is inviting harrassment and worse.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: That is the entire point of the answer. The dress example is only troublesome when mis-using "concern", but not when using "think".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: My first thought I have to admit is a bridesmaid looking better than the bride... :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby- Would it seem better to you if I had given the examples in the opposite order? Saying, '*I think that she looks nice in that dress* is a compliment, but erroneously substituting "My concern is" results in a completely different and undesired sentence?